# I got some files to flash Samsung stock ROM, how to use them with Odin?

Tags: samsung, rom-flashing, device-firmware, odin

*My original problem is at https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/214200/.
You can simply ignore my original problem since it's kinda not related to this question. Just share some backgrounds.*

---

Now, I am trying a different (first stock release) ROM and hopefully, this time, it can work. After downloading this ROM, I got the following 5 files:

```
camera.pit
CODE_GC100XXALJF_413474_REV00_user_low_ship.tar.md5
CSC_HOME_OLB_GC100OLBALJB_409864_REV00_user_low_ship.tar.md5
CSC_OLB_GC100OLBALJB_409864_REV00_user_low_ship.tar.md5
MODEM_GC100XXALJG_REV01_CL1210642.tar.md5
```

I guess `CODE_GC100XXALJF_413474_REV00_user_low_ship.tar.md5` is **AP** option because it has the biggest size. But just a guess.

How to use them with Odin? Which one belongs to which option?

Answer (score 1):

- AP: CODE
- CP: MODEM
- BL: BOOTLOADER (you don't seem to have that)
- CSC: CSC or HOME_CSC
- USERDATA: USERDATA (same for when you need to wipe the user data)

In your case, you'll only need 3 files: AP, MODEM, and CSC/HOME_CSC which contain your carrier-specific files, settings, etc.

Note that the firmware you are trying to flash needs to have the same version as your current version on the device or higher, otherwise you'll get the error you are getting in your third screenshot.

Important: do not use the PIT file as it reparts the internal memory and can cause a brick, and actually it is the cause of the flash failing message, so it is not advised to use it.